# .htaccess rewrite rule foreign characters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site with a page www.domain.com/profile.php?username=|INSERT USERNAME HERE|
Currently, I am able to shorten the URL to www.domain.com/|INSERT USERNAME HERE| with latin (alphanumeric characters.) using this rule:

```
 RewriteRule ^/?([^/.]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [B,QSA,R=301,L]
```

However, when using non-latin characters such as 測試 as a username, www.domain.com/profile.php?username=測試 works perfectly but www.domain.com/測試 returns a 400 Bad Request and a 403 Forbidden error.

Is it possible to shorten a url with foreign characters that returns the profile page?

Comment: I don't see any issue here, did you tested normal characters such as "abcd" to check if rewrite rules working or not?

Comment: All Latin characters work perfectly. Only when adding non Latin characters does it go to crazy error pages.

Comment: are you sure? do you have online demo?

Comment: Should work now. Sorry for delay

Comment: ok, you are right, can you see error logs on server? if not, make sure to contact hosting provider...

Comment: I can and i doubt my hosting provider would let me since I'm with Fatcow...

Comment: OK, turns out Apache version does not support option [B]. What should I do in turn?

Comment: Actually, I'll just revert to using Latin characters only. Big downside for consumers but I guess it's the only way. :(

Comment: :( technical problems like this should be solved by hosting company, I can't help you more about this